# publishing an app for ubuntu software center

Tags: application-development, package-management

I have a game I wish to publish for Ubuntu software center for free.
Can I just zip all my files for submission, or do I need to create a .deb package first before submitting?

Comment: highly related http://askubuntu.com/questions/78136/how-to-comply-with-this-guideline-for-submitting-an-application-to-the-software

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a deb package.
Most info can be found here:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/